# How should I save iOS user actions to balance performance with providing multiple undo?

Tags: iphone, grand-central-dispatch

I have finger painting stuff on one view of my app. When the user touches the view, I save the current view image, so I can undo it later if necessary. To reduce the lag, I fire it using grand central dispatch, something like

```
TouchesBegan method...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self saveCurrentState];
});
```

I have tried different approaches for this saveCurrentState, that is, saving the image to disk, to core data or to an image in memory. The last method is the one that works best, but it doubles the memory usage and brings the app dangerously to a crash by memory usage. The first two methods (saving to disk or to core data) produces a lag so big that if the user draws several lines removing and touching the screen in a fast succession, some lines will not draw, because the program is busy saving one image while the order to save another one arrives.

I have tried to create a serial queue or use one of the 3 main queues of GCD using high priority, but the result is always the same.

How can I solve that? What's the best way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it need to save the image to disk every time it's edited? Maybe you could back up the user actions and save THOSE. Something like:

```
Line(12, 24, 500, 24)
```

Comment: To add, I am not sure if saving the drawing on an image is the correct way to go. You will lose the flexibility of undoing and redoing stuff which I think is a key component when it comes to painting ( on devices at least!). It would make sense that the work be saved in paths rather than an image. This will provide you the flexibility to recreate the image when you come back on, undo and redo stuff, and more importantly saving it to the background won't be much of an hassle.

Comment: it is a problem to save it in paths, because of this: My app offers 50 UNDO/REDO levels. Suppose I am on the last level. Then the user taps UNDO. Then the app has to start drawing from scratch to step 49 in order to recreate what we had then. If you imagine each path as being composed of 50 to 100 points, it is a lot work to do, so an undo may take a long time to happen. Specially because everything is drawn on the drawRect cycle. Using images an UNDO takes 0.1 seconds to happen, but I have this annoying lag problem.

Comment: You are saving images after each user action?

Comment: I testing several possibilities. In the current test, I am doing that for every ToucheBegan. That's one saved image per drawing cycle. I fire a GCD queue to do that but it has a lot of lag and I am open to change this to any other method that works better.

Comment: Keep track of which operations modified which pixels. Suppose the undo button is pressed, and you want to undo a line. Just recalculate the section of screen the line touched. Most operations won't have touched the area you want to recalculate. You would probably only have to recalculate 10 operations or so. Second, you could backup user actions every time, and just save the image every 10 operations. Alternately, instead of saving the whole image every 10 steps, you could just save the areas that would require the most recalculation.

Comment: I have tested this idea in the past, but reading this again gave another ideas to rewrite the drawing and storage method using paths, so I recreated the whole thing and now it is lightning fast. No more files saved to disk. Thanks for all you guys and others who made comments on other answers.

Comment: To add to what Nick said, usually the undo pattern consists of storing the operation in a stack. But, instead of storing "I did draw a line of color x", what you store is the negative action of what the user did, like "I need to draw a line of color Y" to revert to the previous state. Going back through the undo history reverts the image and generates a negative redo buffer for the user. Of course for some actions you will need to store big chunks or the full screen due to their nature, but most paint operations will be lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can improvise on this is to use tiles. So at every point, you only save the tiles that have changed since last write. This way you won't write more than necessary and you will probably reduce the amount of data written out as the user is unlikely to cover much of the drawing board.

So after writing out the tiles that have changed the last iteration, mark all tiles as clean. As the user interacts with the board, mark the tiles that have changed as dirty. After the user is done with his action, write out all the dirty tiles in a concurrent queue. Repeat this over.

You will have to same some metadata as to when the tiles have changed so that you can reconstruct the board at a given iteration so that you can support undo/redo operations.

**Alternately**, you can make improvements to the paths approach by saving images at important junctures like every 5-10 actions so that a undo/redo won't be that costly and the writes aren't either.

Comment: yes, I like this idea of tiles, but I am not seeing exactly what you call by tiles. What do you mean when you say "creating a tile"? Having a method to check the finger coordinate against an array of rects or some other thing?